# Why preloader doesn't work in my React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm making React App (+ Redux), and I want to make preloader when user presses the button `LoginIn`. So, I made thunk like this:

```
export const loginInWithEmail = (email, password) => dispatch => {
    dispatch(loadingAuth(true)) //action which sets loading status
    fire.auth() // auth with email using Firebase
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch((error) => {
            getError(error);
        });
    dispatch(loadingAuth(false))
}
```

Then In my component I made like this:

```
<div>
  {isLoading === true ? <AuthPreloader /> :
    <div>
      {user ? (
        <MainContainer userEmail={userEmail} />
      ) : (
       // component code
    )}
  </div>}
</div>
```

But when I press the button preloder doesn't appear (the system connects me and redirect to `MainContainer` component)

P.S. action and thunk work

Comment: From where `isLoading` is coming?

Comment: @SandipNirmal 'connect' from 'React-Redux'.. For example, when i change state in my Reducer (form false to true, preloader appears)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the Firebase authentication is an asynchronous process and it can take a while. So `dispatch(loadingAuth(false))` is called before the authentication has actually finished.

How you could handle this is by doing something like this:

```
// ...
fire
  .auth() // auth with email using Firebase
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => {
    dispatch(loadingAuth(false));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle error
  });
// ...
```